# when downloading or saving a file in r I can't make R create a directory

Tags: r, windows

Whenever I want to download something to a folder, I have to create the folder manually first. 
for instance:

`download.file("https://ndownloader.figshare.com/files/2292169",
              "data2/portal_data_joined.csv")`

Will give me an error

`cannot open destfile 'data2/portal_data_joined.csv', reason 'No such file or directory'`

My solution is to manually create a folder data2 and then it works. 
My question is: Why doesn't R have the right to create a folder?

Comment: `download.file` does not create `destfile` for you.  You have to create it first, before you can download to it.  Some other functions create files, but not `download.file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has the right, but it chooses not to. It would seem to be fairly common practice to not create folders when R makes a file:

```
> write.table(x,file="./foo/bar/baz.csv")
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file './foo/bar/baz.csv': No such file or directory
```

A neat solution is to create a function, here called `makepath`, that creates the folder at any depth and returns the path back:

```
> makepath = function(path){dir.create(dirname(path),recursive=TRUE);path}
```

Then you can do:

```
> write.table(x,file=makepath("./foo/bar/baz.csv"))
> write.table(x,file=makepath("./foo/bar/qux/moo/baz.csv"))
```

And similarly for `download.file` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dir.create` to create the dir first :)

Answer (score 0):

as Rich Scriven said:

download.file does not create destfile for you. You have to create it first, before you can download to it. Some other functions create files, but not download.file

and Felipe Gerard said:
To create the directory from R use `dir.create("folder")`